# Get notified by email when people fill my form

Tags: php, forms, email

Okey so basically I have a form so if people are interested in getting a website of me so they can fill it out and it was sent directly to my database via a php script. My question is can I do something so that I also get the message with all the information on my email? You can check out my currently script down below.

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME', 'database');
define('DB_USER', 'user');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password'); 
define('DB_HOST', 'server');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD); 

if (!$link){

die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected){

die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

$value = $_POST['ID'];
$value2 = $_POST['name'];
$value3 = $_POST['email'];
$value4 = $_POST['message'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO table (ID, name, email, message) VALUES ('$value', '$value2', '$value3', '$value4')";

if (!mysql_query($sql)){
die('Something went wrong: ' . mysql_error());
} 

header("Location: http://example.com");
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: add `mail();` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: ..generic security warning: your query is wide open to exploitation..

Comment: ..generic mysql_* deprecation warning: switch to PDO or MYSQLi..

Comment: use `mail()` to send emails, http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: You shouldn't be selling websites.